# NFS is not working in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, nfs

I've tried to install NFS but I cannot pass through this step where I configure `/etc/exports`

The file looks as follows:

```
/home/MYUSER/Documents 192.168.0.2(rw, sync, no_subtree_check)
```

But when I restart the `nfs-kernel-server` or run `exportfs -ra` the following appears:

```
* Stopping NFS kernel daemon                                            [ OK ] 
* Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                      [ OK ] 
* Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                               exportfs: /etc/exports:1: syntax error: bad option list
                                                                     [fail]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exports syntax is incorrect – you cannot have any spaces in the option list. Try:

```
/home/MYUSER/Documents 192.168.0.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Comment: I almost cry, thanks a lot, I've been trying this for several hours :')

Comment: Thanks. I wasted my time for this. I think this is a stupid restriction. Almost all languages, scripts ignore whitespaces...